DCG LaTeX printer for FOL prover
The following SWI Prolog code is mainly Jens Ottens' leanseq.pl prover for classical FOL:
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% leanseq.pl - A sequent calculus prover for classical F.O.L. implemented in Prolog 
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(lists)).
% :- use_module(library(ordsets)).
:- use_module(library(time)).
:- use_module(library(terms)).
:- [latex_prop].
% :- [latex_pred].
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% leanseq.pl - A sequent calculus prover for classical F.O.L. implemented in Prolog 
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
% operator definitions (TPTP syntax)
:- op( 500, fy, ~).     % negation
:- op(1000, xfy, &).    % conjunction
:- op(1100, xfy, '|').  % disjunction
:- op(1110, xfy, =>).   % conditional
:- op(1120, xfy, <=>).  % biconditional
:- op( 500, fy, !).             % universal quantifier:  ![X]:
:- op( 500, fy, ?).     % existential quantifier:  ?[X]:
:- op( 500,xfy, :).
*/
% The driver -------------------------------------------------------
decide(Formula) :- 
         prove(Formula).
prove(Formula,I,Proof) :-
        I < 10,
        % print(iteration:I), nl,
        prove([] > [Formula],[],I,1,_,Proof).
prove(Formula,I,Proof) :-
        I1 is I+1,
        I < 10,
        prove(Formula,I1,Proof).
prove(Formula) :-
        time(prove(Formula,1,Proof)),nl,
        write('P_Proof: '),
        portray_clause(Proof),!,
        nl,
      %  buss_tex_print(Proof).
        term_lower_upper(Proof,J),
        nl,
        write('L_Proof: '),nl,nl,
        latex(J,_LaTeX_output),!,
        nl,
        nl.
% -----------------------------------------------------------------
% THE LOGICAL RULES
% 1.The axiom
prove(G > D,_,_,J,J,Proof) :-
        member(A,G),
        A\=(_&_), A\=(_|_), A\=(_=>_),
        A\=(~_), A\=(!_), A\=(?_),
        member(B,D),
        unify_with_occurs_check(A,B),
        Proof = ax(G > D,ax).
% FIRST, NON-BRANCHING RULES %
%% 2. Conditional on the  right
prove(G > D,FV,I,J,K,Proof) :-
        select(A=>B,D,D1), !,
        prove([A|G] > [B|D1],FV,I,J,K,Rule_applied),
        Proof = r_to(G > D, Rule_applied).
%% 3. Disjunction on the right
prove(G > D,FV,I,J,K,Proof) :-
        select(A|B,D,D1), !,
        prove(G > [A,B|D1],FV,I,J,K,Rule_applied),
        Proof = r_lor(G > D, Rule_applied).
%% 4. Conjunction on the left
prove(G > D,FV,I,J,K,Proof) :-
        select(A&B,G,G1), !,
        prove([A,B|G1] > D,FV,I,J,K,Rule_applied),
        Proof = l_land(G > D, Rule_applied).
%% 5. Negation on the right
prove(G > D,FV,I,J,K,Proof) :-
        select(~A,D,D1), !,
        prove([A|G] > D1,FV,I,J,K,Rule_applied),
        Proof = r_neg(G > D, Rule_applied).
%% 6. Negation on the left
prove(G > D,FV,I,J,K,Proof) :-
        select(~A,G,G1), !,
        prove(G1 > [A|D],FV,I,J,K,Rule_applied),
        Proof = l_neg(G > D, Rule_applied).
% SECOND, BRANCHING PROPOSITIONAL LOGIC RULES %
%% 7. Conditional on the left   
prove(G > D,FV,I,J,K,Proof) :-
        select(A=>B,G,G1), !,
        prove(G1 > [A|D],FV,I,J,J1,Rule_applied1),
        prove([B|G1] > D,FV,I,J1,K,Rule_applied2),
        Proof = l_to(G > D, Rule_applied1, Rule_applied2).
%% 8. Conjunction on the right
prove(G > D,FV,I,J,K,Proof) :-
        select(A&B,D,D1), !,
        prove(G > [A|D1],FV,I,J,J1,Rule_applied1),
        prove(G > [B|D1],FV,I,J1,K,Rule_applied2),
        Proof = r_land(G > D, Rule_applied1, Rule_applied2).
%% 9. Disjunction on the left
prove(G > D,FV,I,J,K,Proof) :-
        select(A|B,G,G1), !,
        prove([A|G1] > D,FV,I,J,J1,Rule_applied1),
        prove([B|G1] > D,FV,I,J1,K,Rule_applied2),
        Proof = l_lor(G > D, Rule_applied1, Rule_applied2).
% 10. Biconditional on the right
prove(G>D,FV,I,J,K,Proof) :-
        select((A<=>B),D,D1),!,
        prove([A|G]>[B|D1],FV,I,J,J1,Rule_applied1),
        prove([B|G]>[A|D1],FV,I,J1,K,Rule_applied2),
        Proof = l_leftrightarrow(G > D, Rule_applied1, Rule_applied2).
%% 11. Biconditional on the left
prove(G>D,FV,I,J,K,Proof):-
        select((A<=>B),G,G1),!,
        prove([A,B|G1]>D,FV,I,J,J1,Rule_applied1),
        prove(G1>[A,B|D],FV,I,J1,K,Rule_applied2),
        Proof = l_leftrightarrow(G > D, Rule_applied1, Rule_applied2).
%% QUANTIFICATION RULES 
% 12. universal quantifier on the right
prove(G > D,FV,I,J,K,Proof) :-
        select((![X]:A),D,D1),!,
        copy_term((X:A,FV),(f_sk(J,FV):A1,FV)),
        J1 is J+1, 
        prove(G > [A1|D1],FV,I,J1,K,Rule_applied),
        Proof = r_forall(G > D, Rule_applied).
% 13. existential quantifier on the left 
prove(G > D,FV,I,J,K,Proof) :-
        select((?[X]:A),G,G1),!,
        copy_term((X:A,FV),(f_sk(J,FV):A1,FV)),
        J1 is J+1,
        prove([A1|G1] > D,FV,I,J1,K,Rule_applied),
        Proof = l_exists(G > D, Rule_applied).
   % 14. existential quantifier on the right 
prove(G > D,FV,I,J,K,Proof) :-
        member((?[X]:A),D),
        \+ length(FV,I),
        copy_term((X:A,FV),(Y:A1,FV)),
        prove(G > [A1|D],[Y|FV],I,J,K,Rule_applied),
        Proof = r_exists(G > D, Rule_applied).
% 15. universal quantifier on the left
prove(G > D,FV,I,J,K,Proof) :-
        member((![X]:A),G),
        \+ length(FV,I),
        copy_term((X:A,FV),(Y:A1,FV)),
        prove([A1|G] > D,[Y|FV],I,J,K,Rule_applied),
        Proof = l_forall(G > D, Rule_applied).
%% END of leanseq.pl code       %


and its printer in DCGs notation, that works only for the case of propositional logic:

:- op( 500, fy, ~).             % negation
:- op(1000, xfy, &).    % conjunction
:- op(1100, xfy, '|').  % disjunction
:- op(1110, xfy, =>).   % conditional
:- op(1120, xfy, <=>).  % biconditional
:- op( 500, fy, !).     % universal quantifier:  ![X]:
:- op( 500, fy, ?).     % existential quantifier:  ?[X]:
:- op( 500,xfy, :).

/*
Now, to upcase atomic variables in LaTeX output, the following code is Carlo Capelli's
https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/how-to-use-of-upcase-atom-2-to-get-uppercase-letters-in-an-output/4693/118
<https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/how-to-use-of-upcase-atom-2-to-get-uppercase-letters-in-an-output/4693/123?u=joseph-vidal-rosset
*/

term_lower_upper(Lower, Upper) :-
    (   compound(Lower)
    ->  mapargs(term_lower_upper, Lower, Upper)
    ;   is_list(Lower)
    ->  maplist(term_lower_upper, Lower, Upper)
    ;   var(Lower)
    ->  Upper = Lower
    ;   atomic(Lower) % Check if Lower is an atomic term
    ->  upcase_atom(Lower, Upper) % Capitalize atoms for propositional calculus
    ;   throw(term_lower_upper(Lower, Upper))
    ).

/******************************************************************/
/* Pretty Printing  for propostional calculus                                     */
/******************************************************************/

atom_split('', _, []) :- !. % Handle empty string case and cut to prevent backtracking

atom_split(X, D, L) :-
    atomic_list_concat(L, D, X).

latex(H, J) :-
    latex_root(H, J, L, []),
    atom_split(Y, '', L),
    write(Y),nl.

latex_root(P, J) -->
        ['\\begin{prooftree}\n'],
        latex_proof(P, J),
        ['\\end{prooftree}\n'].

latex_proof(ax(S,U), J) -->
        ['\\AxiomC{}\n \\RightLabel{$Ax.$}\n \\UnaryInfC{$'],
        latex_sequent(S, ax(S,U), J),
        ['$}\n'].
latex_proof(r_to(S,P), J) -->
        latex_proof(P, J),
        ['\\RightLabel{$R\\to$}\n \\UnaryInfC{$'],
        latex_sequent(S, r_to(S,P), J),
        ['$}\n'].
latex_proof(l_land(S,P), J) -->
        latex_proof(P, J),
        ['\\RightLabel{$L\\land$}\n \\UnaryInfC{$'],
        latex_sequent(S, l_land(S,P), J),
        ['$}\n'].
latex_proof(r_lor(S,P), J) -->
        latex_proof(P, J),
        ['\\RightLabel{$R\\lor$}\n \\UnaryInfC{$'],
        latex_sequent(S, r_lor(S,P), J),
        ['$}\n'].
latex_proof(l_neg(S,P), J) -->
        latex_proof(P, J),
        ['\\RightLabel{$L\\neg$}\n \\UnaryInfC{$'],
        latex_sequent(S, l_neg(S,P), J),
        ['$}\n'].
latex_proof(r_neg(S,P), J) -->
        latex_proof(P, J),
        ['\\RightLabel{$R\\neg$}\n \\UnaryInfC{$'],
        latex_sequent(S, r_neg(S,P), J),
        ['$}\n'].
latex_proof(r_land(S,P,Q), J) -->
        latex_proof(P, J),
        latex_proof(Q, J),
        ['\\RightLabel{$R\\land$}\n \\BinaryInfC{$'],
        latex_sequent(S, r_land(S,P,Q), J),
        ['$}\n'].
latex_proof(l_lor(S,P,Q), J) -->
        latex_proof(P, J),
        latex_proof(Q, J),
        ['\\RightLabel{$L\\lor$}\n \\BinaryInfC{$'],
        latex_sequent(S, l_lor(S,P,Q), J),
        ['$}\n'].
latex_proof(l_to(S,P,Q), J) -->
        latex_proof(P, J),
        latex_proof(Q, J),
        ['\\RightLabel{$L\\to$}\n \\BinaryInfC{$'],
        latex_sequent(S, l_to(S,P,Q), J),
        ['$}\n'].
latex_proof(l_leftrightarrow(S,P,Q), J) -->
        latex_proof(P, J),
        latex_proof(Q, J),
        ['\\RightLabel{$R\\leftrightarrow$}\n \\BinaryInfC{$'],
        latex_sequent(S, l_leftrightarrowd(S,P,Q), J),
        ['$}\n'].
latex_proof(r_leftrightarrow(S,P,Q), J) -->
        latex_proof(P, J),
        latex_proof(Q, J),
        ['\\RightLabel{$R\\leftrightarrow$}\n \\BinaryInfC{$'],
        latex_sequent(S, r_leftrightarrow(S,P,Q), J),
        ['$}\n'].

latex_sequent(G > D, _, J) -->
        latex_list(G, 0, J),
        [' \\vdash '],
        latex_list(D, 0, J).

latex_list([X|L], N, J) -->
        latex_formula(X, J),
        {M is N+1},
        latex_rest(L, M, J).
latex_list([_|L], N, J) -->
        {M is N+1},
        latex_list(L, M, J).

latex_list([], _,_) -->
        [].

latex_rest([X|L], N, J) -->
        [' , '],
        latex_formula(X, J),
        {M is N+1},
        latex_rest(L, M, J).
latex_rest([_|L], N, J) -->
        {M is N+1},
        latex_rest(L, M, J).

latex_rest([], _, _) -->
        [].

latex_formula(~A, J) -->
        !,
        ['\\neg '],
        latex_formula(A, J).
latex_formula((A&B), J) -->
        !,
        latex_formula(A, J),
        [' \\land '],
        latex_formula(B, J).
latex_formula((A|B), J) -->
        !,
        latex_formula(A, J),
        [' \\lor '],
        latex_formula(B, J).
latex_formula((A=>B), J) -->
        !,
         latex_formula(A, J),
        [' \\to '],
        latex_formula(B, J).
latex_formula((A<=>B), J) -->
        !,
        latex_formula(A, J),
        [' \\leftrightarrow '],
        latex_formula(B, J).

latex_formula(X, J) -->
        latex_factor(X, J).

latex_factor(X, _) -->
        [X].

I do not succeed to complete this printer to get LaTeX (bussproofs.sty) proofs for theorems of classical first order logic. I would be glad if someone would succeed to dot it and would share the code to complete the printer.
Minimal examples: the prover and the printer in the same directory, consult the prover, and see that, except complexity issue, any theorem of classical propositional logic is provable, and that the output is both is given both via portray_clause/1 and in bussproofs.sty LaTeX format :
?- decide(~ ~ p => p).
% 46 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (97% CPU, 2196543 Lips)

P_Proof: r_to([]>[(~ ~p=>p)],
              l_neg([~ ~p]>[p], r_neg([]>[~p, p], ax([p]>[p], ax)))).


L_Proof: 

\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{}
 \RightLabel{$Ax.$}
 \UnaryInfC{$P \vdash P$}
\RightLabel{$R\neg$}
 \UnaryInfC{$ \vdash \neg P , P$}
\RightLabel{$L\neg$}
 \UnaryInfC{$\neg \neg P \vdash P$}
\RightLabel{$R\to$}
 \UnaryInfC{$ \vdash \neg \neg P \to P$}
\end{prooftree}

true.


By contrast with any theorem of first order predicate calculus:
?- decide(f(a) => ?[X]: f(X)).
% 59 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (94% CPU, 701396 Lips)

P_Proof: r_to([]>[(f(a)=> ?[A]:f(A))],
              r_exists([f(a)]>[?[A]:f(A)],
                       ax([f(a)]>[f(a), ?[A]:f(A)], ax))).


L_Proof: 

false.

?- decide(![X]:f(X) => f(a)). 
% 57 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (94% CPU, 680142 Lips)

P_Proof: r_to([]>[(![A]:f(A)=>f(a))],
              l_forall([![A]:f(A)]>[f(a)],
                       ax([f(a), ![A]:f(A)]>[f(a)], ax))).


L_Proof: 

false.

I do not know if it is possible to complete the printer file in order to provide LaTeX proofs for any classical FOL theorem in the case of this prover, but it is challenging.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and improve the question. Can debug: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

@brebs I hope that these minimal examples help. Comments in the prover file are sufficient to identify what are the rules the predicate logic that must be implemented in the printer file. I do not know how to be clearer.

Generally, "please help me complete this code" questions are frowned upon on Stackoverflow.

Use trace to debug - it shows failure at latex_proof(r_exists([f(_106438)]>[?[_106444]:f(_106444)], ax([f(_106438)]>[f(_106438), ?[_106444]:f(_106444)], _106590)), _106608, _110170, _113406) because there is no latex_proof(r_exists... predicate.

@brebs Thanks. The result of this trace is not surprising: at the moment the printer works only for propositional logic. I have deleted all my tentative of extending the printer to predicate logic, because all of them failed. This is certainly not a trivial task, because of invividual variables, individual constants, Skolem functions, etc.  Competences both in mathematical logic and in Prolog programming are needed.

How does your raw Latex look like when you render it. Whats exactly the problem?

The problem lies in the definition of DCGs rules to get proofs in first order predicate logic for bussproofs.sty format. Using what has been written for the propositional case is not enough and everything fails, contrarily to Prolog outputs that are  fine. The goal is to translate them in LaTex format (bussproofs.sty).

How does your raw Latex look like when you
render it. What is exactly the problem?
I don’t find much problem for propositional logic,
basically using the Curry Howard isomorphism:
:- show((p => p & ~ ~p)).


